# Facebook Open Graph warning on multiple fb:admins

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm getting a Facebook Open Graph debugger warning when I put two admins in the `fb:admins` meta value. With a single admin, it passes fine, but with two I get a warning. Everything works fine, but my OCD wants to get it right. Any help?

Here's my code:

```html
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# article: http://ogp.me/ns/article#">

    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="122146944552301"/>
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="15901643,15932442"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://uamedia.missouri.edu/mizmag/facebook-test.html" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="UA Media" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Facebook Test" />

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <title>Facebook Test</title>
</head>
```

And I get this error:

> **Parser Mismatched Metadata** The parser's result for this metadata did not match the input metadata. Likely, this was caused by the data
>   being ordered in an unexpected way, multiple values being given for a
>   property only expecting a single value, or property values for a given
>   property being mismatched. Here are the input properties that were not
>   seen in the parsed result: 'fb:admins'

Any ideas?

Comment: @MicheleOrsi I have no idea why. I've tried many different ways to fix it. Really hope someone sees this.

Comment: same here, changed to 1 admin for now.

Comment: I've also started receiving this error. Although, everything seems to have linked up OK (the admins are able to administer the site still).

Comment: @DanMurfitt I have noticed that as well. Even though I get warnings, everything works just fine. I think it's my anal retentiveness that's wanting to make it right.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

you have to use the array format [[http://ogp.me/#array]](http://ogp.me/#array)

In your example:

instead of

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="15901643,15932442"/>
```

you have to use

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="15901643"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="15932442"/>
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks, Kai! It would be nice if Facebook documented it correctly.

Comment: biggest problem with any of this is Facebook doesn't document this sh*t... so annoying. I'll work in the update into the next version of my WP plugin. (until they change it again, cause it never used to throw that warning)

Comment: I have been looking for this all morning. FB does a very poor job with the open Graph documentation, and working with wordpress only makes matters a lil bit more difficult. Thanks for this answer!

Comment: I. HATE. Facebook. This annoyance has been plaguing us for over a year. Worst part? We took the multiple fb:admins thing from Facebook DOCUMENTATION. They never, ever, ever seem to have their s-word together.

Comment: It is even more confusing as FB uses the comma separated version in their documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/#claiming_a_domain

Answer (score 2):

I've updated Facebook's documentation to include the right directions for more than one admin.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: THANK YOU! The documentation (probably circa early 2012) defined it as "000,000" not two tags.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please update https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices as well? Also linking to the documentation in your answer would be great.

Answer (score -2):

in my oppinion, only the last meta tag will count for the code that uses the property value.

although meta should go in the head, you can use them anywhere and anytime on the page. just keep in mind the parser goes through the code and compiles all the lines in order.

you can even use the [IF] to select the code to be parsed according to certain global conditions.

Comment: `...you can use them anywhere and anytime on the page.` This is not true. FB will not read meta tags in the `<body>`