# multiple fb:admins in og tags

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

Short question concerning the og-tag **fb:admins**: According to the OpenGraph-documentation the value for multiple admins should be comma separated:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="609190863,100002012872577,..." />
```

Unfortunately, Facebook Debugger informs you, that the specified format isn't correct. When you change the code to the following, everything's fine:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="609190863" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="100002012872577" />
```

Debugger says "All fine".

So my question:

Was there any change in the mentioned og tag in the last weeks or is it a bug of the debugger itself?

Fun fact: In both code examples the parsed output of the admin sections is the same and displayed correctly as an array.

(compare: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=allfacebook.de)

Comment: Perhaps this should be reported to Facebook.  Not much the users of [so] can do about it. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: @lix: of course, but i'm interested in the community experience as well. maybe i missed an announcement.

Answer (score 1):

looks like my first guess was correct: See [Facebook Open Graph warning on multiple fb:admins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868232/facebook-open-graph-warning-on-multiple-fbadmins) for more info on this one.